# Comparing two arrays and fill in missing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to compare the dates from 2 arrays and push the name from the matching date inside a new array. And then push '0' for missing dates.

This is what I've tried

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Amy',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  date: '2020-01-02'
}, {
  name: 'Sara',
  date: '2020-01-04'
}];

var fulldate = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'];
var newData = [];
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (data[i].date == fulldate[i]) {
    newData.push(data[i].name);
  } else if (data[i].date != fulldate[i]) {
    newData.push("0")
  }
}

console.log(newData);
```

The problem is that it stops after encountering the unmatched date:

```
Amy,John,0
```

This is what I need

```
Amy, John, 0, Sara, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is always to use `map` and `filter`. Use map function on the `fulldate` The `obj` filters out the object (if present) with same date, as of current `el` value. I have used ternary operator in the return statement which returns name if object is present, and 0 otherwise.

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Amy',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  date: '2020-01-02'
}, {
  name: 'Sara',
  date: '2020-01-04'
}];

var fulldate = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'];


var result = fulldate.map((el) => {
  let obj = data.filter(item => (item.date == el))  
  return (obj[0]) ? obj[0].name : 0;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It helps and is much simpler. I gotta study more about map and filter

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the arrays are ordered by date already, use a variable `dataIdx` to iterate `data` and `Array.map()` to simplify the for loop.

```js
var data = [{name:'Amy', date:'2020-01-01'}, {name:'John', date:'2020-01-02'}, {name:'Sara', date:'2020-01-04'}];

var fulldate = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'];

var dataIdx = 0;
var newData = fulldate.map(date => data[dataIdx] && data[dataIdx].date == date ? data[dataIdx++].name : '0');
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

For shortest solution you should combine map and find. Here is a oneliner:

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Amy',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  date: '2020-01-02'
}, {
  name: 'Sara',
  date: '2020-01-04'
}];

const fulldate = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'];

const result = fulldate.map(x => (data.find(y => y.date === x) || {name: 0}).name)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

- On your code, you have used `for-loop` based on `data` variable length but the result has the same length with `fulldate` so it will be looped based on `fulldate` variable length.
- Inside loop, you have compared `fulldate[i] == data[i].date` so compared only same index. Inside the loop, you need to use another loop to find the index of the matched date.

Instead of using `for` loop, you can simply do it using `Array.prototype.map` function. (Inside map function, using `Array.prototype.findIndex`, you can find the matched date index.)

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Amy',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  date: '2020-01-02'
}, {
  name: 'Sara',
  date: '2020-01-04'
}];

var fulldate = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'];

const result = fulldate.map((date) => {
  const existed = data.findIndex(item => item.date === date);
  return existed >= 0 ? data[existed].name : 0
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the found index is used to return name.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. In that case, `.find`. You are already looping, just get the object instead. `const {name} = data.find(item => item.date === date); return name || '0'`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Amy',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  date: '2020-01-02'
}, {
  name: 'Sara',
  date: '2020-01-04'
}];
var fulldate = [
  '2020-01-01',
  '2020-01-02',
  '2020-01-03',
  '2020-01-04',
  '2020-01-05'
];
var newData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < fulldate.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for(var k in data) {
    if(data[k].date == fulldate[i]) {
      newData.push(data[k].name);
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found)
    newData.push("0");
}
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

for variable declaration, use 'let' or 'const' instead of var. reason: [var vs let vs const](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

And, the result you are looking for can be done using map & find js func.

```js
const fulldate = ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05"];
const data = [
 {name: "Amy", date: "2020-01-01"},
 {name: "John", date: "2020-01-02"},
 {name: "Sara", date: "2020-01-04"}
];

const result = fulldate.map(date => {
    const matchingDate = data.find(nameDateObj => nameDateObj['date'] === date);
    return matchingDate ? matchingDate['name'] : 0;
});

console.log(result)
```

fyi: this can also be done using findIndex instead of find too.

```
fulldate.map(date => {
     const matchingDateIndex = data.findIndex(nameDateObj => nameDateObj['date'] === date);
     return matchingDateIndex > -1 ? data[matchingDateIndex]['name'] : 0; 
});
```